# MySQL, Select field depending on multiple other rows in table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm implementing a messaging system on my site, and have a table to store the conversation participants like so:

```
conversation_id     user_id
3                   2   
3                   28  
4                   1   
4                   2   
5                   1   
5                   2 
5                   28
```

I can't find a query that will let me check if a conversation already exists between 2 users (or more). I basically want `3` (conversation_id) to be returned if user `2` is sending to user `28`, or vice-versa, like that I can keep the conversation going even if they haven't explicitly replied to a previous message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `having` clause you can filter to only the `conversation_id`s where **both** users participate

```
select conversation_id
from your_table
where user_id in (2, 28)
group by conversation_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2
```